# Как сделать так, чтобы каждый вариант изменения писался с новой строки

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
my_file = open("Data.txt", "w+")
Data="Hi"
next_line="\n"
my_file.write(Data)
my_file.write(next_line)
my_file.close()
```

Представьте, что переменная "Data" изменит свое значение во время работы программы.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```py
my_file = open("Data.txt", "w+")
Data='Hi'
next_line='\n'
my_file.write(Data+next_line)
my_file.close()
```

Но если бы я делал по своему то я бы не давал имя каждому символу и воспользовался другой конструкцией:

```py
with open('Data.txt', 'w+') as file:
    Data='Hi'
    file.Write(Data+'\n')
```